# Ffmpeg: change filter options after running ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Is it possible to change filter options (picture in picture overlay position for example) after ffmpeg is started?

Comment: Using a FFmpeg filter with [libzmq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq) linked, I believe you can, for filters which support commands. The overlay filter does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently issue is resolved, thanks [Mulvya](https://superuser.com/users/114058/mulvya) for the aiming.

Basic usage example:

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -re -y -i master_video.mov -i pip_video.mov \
-filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2:ih/2 [pip]; [pip] zmq,[0]overlay=x=0:y=0" \
-f mpegts -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast result.mp4
```

Use next commands for change coordinates:

```
echo Parsed_overlay_2 x 200 | zmqsend
echo Parsed_overlay_2 y 200 | zmqsend
```